# Wordpress running very slow on a vagrant virtual machine

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, vagrant

I have set up a vagrant virtual machine with ubuntu, php, nginx and mysql to run a wordpress site.

The problem is running very slot and I usually get the 502 bad gateway error. I've also configured the site using mamp in my mac and it goes like 4x faster.

Any ideas on how to improve the virtual machine performance?

Here's my nginx config file:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name {{www_domain}};
root   {{www_document_root}};
index index.php;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/{{phpmyadmin_domain}}.access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/{{phpmyadmin_domain}}.error.log error;

# serve static files directly
location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt)$ {
    access_log        off;
    expires           max;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}

location ~ .php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 64k;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 64k;
}}
```

And here's the VagrantFile config:

Answer (score 3):

Try increasing the amount of memory and CPU that the VM has access to:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  v.memory = 2048
  v.cpus = 2
end
```